# How to make whole longtable align to the top?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

```
\item
\begin{longtable}[l]{l l}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 \\
\end{longtable}
```

Inside an `enumerate` environment, the above code produces a `longtable` that is not beside the item number but rather before it. If I don't need a multi-page table, the following does exactly what I want:

```
\item
\begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 \\
\end{tabular}
```

but I do need a multi-page table. How to make `longtable` vertically align to the top (like the `tabular` example)? I am open to replacing `longtable` with `tabularx`, `xtabular`, or `longtabu` if they can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating a little on [Harish Kumar's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223377/27635), you'll probably want the `longtable` to the left.

To do that, don't use the optional argument for `longtable` but issue

```
\setlength{\LTleft}{\leftmargin}
```

This should give you what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \mbox{}\vspace*{-1.68\baselineskip}\setlength{\LTleft}{\leftmargin}
        \begin{longtable}{l l}
            1 & 2 \\
            3 & 4 \\
            5 & 6 \\
        \end{longtable}
    \item another item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

or, if you prefer perfect alignment (thanks Mico for the comment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \mbox{}\vspace*{-1.68\baselineskip}\setlength{\LTleft}{\leftmargin}
        \begin{longtable}{@{} l l}
            1 & 2 \\
            3 & 4 \\
            5 & 6 \\
        \end{longtable}
    \item another item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Refining this approach even further, one could specify `\begin{longtable}{@{} l l}` instead of `\begin{longtable}{l l}`. This will align the left-hand edge of the table with the starting position of the other `item`s.

Answer (score 4):

Things can get dirty always, but that is life. Here is a dirty and quick method..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \hrule\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \mbox{}\vspace{-1.66\baselineskip}  %% adjust this 1.66
        \begin{longtable}{l l}
            1 & 2 \\
            3 & 4 \\
            5 & 6 \\
        \end{longtable}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]